# Integer Program with Pulp: Extending time constraint

Tags: pulp

I have an integer program that schedules 'slots' of time for instructors and students using the constraint:

> ```
> for req in reqs:
>     sked_model += sum([x[slot] for slot in slots if ('0', 'art', req[2]) == (slot[4], slot[1], slot[3])]) == 1, ""
> ```

I need to create an additional constraint that also schedules the period immediately following for the same teacher and student. Other information:

> The 'slots' represent tuples of (time, course, instructor, student, grade).
>   The 'reqs' also represent tuples of (grade, course, student)

Answer (score 0):

I would create another 0,1 variable that represents the decision that the two slots are allocated to the the student and the teacher

i.e. for the 2nd and 3rd slot for student s and teacher t

`x(2,3),s,t`

Then add constraints that reflect that decision
i.e

`x2,s,t >= x(2,3),s,t
x3,s,t >= x(2,3),s,t`

And see how it goes, if this becomes intractable you could look at a-priory defining days for students or teachers and allocating that in your formulation.

have a look at https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1848/cee0d33b41b765427909297d69b8956be5f2.pdf for some other formulations